# Deformation in nano timescales for stress > UTS

Tags: finite-element-method, deformation

I am investigating the deformation of high-strength carbon steel past its UTS, subject to extreme pressures of order 1e+19 Pa, but applied in small timescales (100-500 ns). For a material, such as steel in this situation, I assume modeling the deformation due to fractures and necking in a short timeframe is the most applicable model, but I am unsure of how to model such a complex task and how to apply it to an FEA package, such as Ansys.

If anyone comes across any papers, formulas, tutorials, or anything that is similar to this, that would be much appreciated, I am quite stuck.

**Update; As of 01/10/23**

It appears that Ansys continues to model the strains even past the UTS, is there a way to tell Ansys to start modeling the fracture or neck of a material after a certain point? Thank you for @niels nielsen suggestion to look into Impact Extrusion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how the materials scientist responds.

What you are describing is called *high energy-rate forming*. This occurs when the speed with which you deform the material exceeds its capacity to conduct away the heat from internal friction, which means the material becomes red-hot in an instant and flows as if it were molten.

It is also called *impact extrusion* which is how aluminum beer cans are made. It's high energy rate forming where the material doesn't get red hot but hot enough to flow like taffy- simply by being whacked really, really hard in an instant.

Search on those key words for more info.

Comment: I have updated my question a little, this is helpful, thank you.